# Difference between CSR creation and create domain certificate

Tags: certificate-authority, csr, self-signed-certificate

I'm a CA admin and I'm new to this field, Can any one explain the below scenario and explain the difference between them.

**Scenario 1**

> System Admin creates a CSR file and give it to me... I will generate a
>   certificate by CSR file and issue it back to System admin

**Scenario 2**

> System admin select the option " create domain certificate " instead
>   of CSR file.

What is the difference between them can anyone please explain this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, because "create domain certificate" option in IIS automatically creates CSR, submits it to CA server (ADCS) and installs it to web server. First option is manual process, second one is automatic.

Comment: So CA admin is not require to create and issue certificates? all the sys admin can do this to get certificates right... sorry if my question is silly..!!

Answer (score 0):

This depending on where you are a CA admin, and how the certificate will be used.

**Option A:** In large corporate networks, usually have a **Domain Controller** os **SSO (Single Sign-On)** setup using **Microsoft Active Directory** and so on. In this case, you can set up a **CA server** that in a more automatic way will issue certs that are trusted on your "domain", basically your intranet ecosystem of **Active Directory** and the PCs that connect to it, directly or through VPN connections.

**Option B:** If you are a CA admin of a hosting company where **SSL/TLS Certificates** need to be trusted over the internet by the public, you need an independent certificate authority's certificate that is trusted by browsers by default. For this, you can only use the CSR ("Create Certificate Request...") option, since you need to provide the CSR text to the **Certificate Authority**. They will then return the signed certificate that you install on IIS. Using the "**Complete Certificate Request...**".